# How can I use C code in a C# Project? Wrapper class?

Tags: c#, c, interop, wrapper

I have a C code and I want to use this in C#.

Is there a possibillity except rewriting this code?

Answer (score 7):

Build the C code as a DLL, and then use "P/Invoke" to call it. You'll need to learn a bit about interop, which is an area I don't know very much about, I'm afraid – but here are a few links:

- [A rather old article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx), but it looks fairly good
- [BCL Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/06/23/p-invoke-interop-assistant-justin-van-patten.aspx) talking about the P/Invoke Interop Assistant
- A [recent MSDN Magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx)
- The [MSDN interop guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd10k43k.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here i got a great tool ,[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) , can do that. which support a lot of different language, include C# and java.